# Breakpoints not working with eclipse, xdebug and phpcli

Tags: php, eclipse, xdebug

Breakpoints are being ignored when running xdebug with phpcli in Eclipse. The first breakpoint works, but the others I set manually don't.

I looked at xdebug.remote_log found the following:

<- breakpoint_set -i 671 -t line -f **file:///home/jlam/code/makhai/public/index.php** -n 6
->

<- breakpoint_set -i 672 -t line -f **file:///org.eclipse.dltk.core.environment.localEnvironment/:/home/jlam/lib/ZF2/Zend/ModuleManager/ModuleManager.php** -n 170
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="672" id="235390002"></response>

... which leads me to beleive that I could fix it if either:

1. I find a way for Eclipse to remove the "/org.eclipse.dltk.core.environment.localEnvironment/:"
2. Make that location valid (create an entry in hosts file?)
3. Modify properties (the PHP Include Path) of the Eclipse project so that external sources (to what I don't know)

Thank you for your contributions.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.
Open the file directly(File->Open File->) and set breakpoints.